# Magento2 $ is not a function when using flexslider

Tags: magento2, jquery

I just migrated from Magento 1.x to Magento 2.

I setup Magento successfully, understood and used RequireJS as well.

I was adding flexslider on my home page and got the error:

```
$ is not a function
```

which means either jQuery is not loaded or there is a conflict. When I checked the network, I see jQuery is loaded successfully and jquery.flexslider-min.js is loaded after jQuery.

So, I'm not able to find the problem.

Here is my requirejs-config.js under my theme directory:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        flexslider: 'Mymodule_Test/js/jquery.flexslider-min',
        header: 'Mymodule_Test/js/store/header'
    }
}
};
```

and there is part of my template:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

require(['jquery', 'flexslider'],function($, flexslider){
    (function() {
        $(window).load(function () {
            $('.flexslider').flexslider();
        });
    })(jQuery);
});
</script>
```

Please help me!

Comment: How did you end up resolving the issue?

Answer (score 2):

try this :

```
require(['jquery', 'flexslider'], function($) {
    $(document).ready(function($) {
        $('.flexslider').flexslider();
    });
});
```